# Rspec controller show test failing with rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple rspec test which is failing after I upgrade to 3.2.6.

Here is the spec in users_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "show action" do
  before(:each) do
    User.stub!(:find).with(@user.id).and_return(@user)
  end

  def do_get
    get :show, :id => @user.id
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    do_get
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

and here is the error

```
1) UsersController show action should be successful
 Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user.id
   .........................
(class)> received :find with unexpected arguments
expected: (2)
got: ("2")
```

Not sure where is going wrong. The show action has nothing in the controller, it is just

```
def show
end
```